# List Selection not working for custom view in swift

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've been trying to sort out selections of items in a List, and first had to find the simplest possible example, which works. If you click on an item, it is highlighted, and the text box at the bottom shows the selected item.

```
struct ListTest1: View {
  @State private var selection: String?

  let names = [
      "Cyril",
      "Lana",
      "Mallory",
      "Sterling"
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List(names, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { contact in
        Text(contact)
      }
      Text("\(selection ?? "N/A")")
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to use a simple custom view with a struct holding data, nothing works.

```
struct testData: Hashable {
  var name = ""
  var id = UUID()
}

struct ListTest2: View {
  @State private var selection: testData?

  let names = [
    testData(name: "Cyril"),
    testData(name: "Lana"),
    testData(name: "Mallory"),
    testData(name: "Sterling")
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List(names, id: \.id, selection: $selection) { contact in
        Text(contact.name)
      }
      Text("\((selection == nil) ? "N/A" : selection!.name)")
    }
  }
}
```

The item isn't highlighted or selected in the bottom text block. I'm sure there is a
simple explanation but I don't understand enough about the internals to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selection` stores the `ID` of the item -- not the item itself. The `ID` is the default `tag` given to the item in the `List`

This updated code works:

```
struct testData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name = ""
    var id = UUID()
}

struct ListTest2: View {
    @State private var selection: testData.ID?
    
    let names = [
        testData(name: "Cyril"),
        testData(name: "Lana"),
        testData(name: "Mallory"),
        testData(name: "Sterling")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(names, selection: $selection) { contact in
                Text(contact.name)
            }
            if let item = names.first(where: { $0.id == selection }) {
                Text(item.name)
            } else {
                Text("N/A")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you really wanted the item itself, you could use `tag`:

```
struct testData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name = ""
    var id = UUID()
}

struct ListTest2: View {
    @State private var selection: testData?
    
    let names = [
        testData(name: "Cyril"),
        testData(name: "Lana"),
        testData(name: "Mallory"),
        testData(name: "Sterling")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(names, selection: $selection) { contact in
                Text(contact.name).tag(contact)
            }
            if let selection {
                Text(selection.name)
            } else {
                Text("N/A")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that on the second example, if you had a more complicated model and that model were mutable, if a property changed on the model, the selection would become invalid. By using `Identifiable`, like the first example, you avoid that issue.

Comment: It took me a while to digest this. One reason is that I could not understand why simple List selection examples I saw on the net didn't require using the ID. Now that I've stared at it for a while, I think I understand. It's because for those examples, the ID field for the Identifiable protocol is \.self. Is that correct?

Comment: The `id` field for `Identifiable` is `id`, not `self`

Comment: One more question. Why is the id declared lowercase but the selection variable is ID uppercase? Computed property of Identifiable?

Comment: See this example for where I got the id of \.self

https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-selection/

Comment: "We declare a variable of tyle optional string (String?) because Identifiable.ID is \.self, which refers to the data string itself." from the page above

Comment: `Identifiable` has an `associatedtype ID : Hashable` -- that's the capitalized one. The property itself is `var id: Self.ID { get }`. Regarding using `self` as an ID, it works in a trivial case like the one you linked to, where nothing about the array ever changes. But it doesn't work as an actual identifier most of the time and is generally a bad idea. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for more information.

Comment: Also the "We declare a variable of tyle optional string (String?) because Identifiable.ID is \.self" is not actually correct. What's actually happening is `.self` is being used as a key path to provide an ID to something that is _not_ `Identifiable`.